# Send different type of data, modify it before validation to fit?

Tags: python, django, rest, django-rest-framework

I didn't found any solution that would clear my problem. Althought it is maybe not by rest convection to receive one type of data and send back other type. Let's say that something like this would be practical for me.

I have Serializer that combines two more serializers. The issue that appeared to me is with related `articles` and `keywords` fields in `ArticleSerializer`, to be precise in inserting those two fields which are in fact related objects. to start code of serializers looks like this:

```
class ArticleAuthorsSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    related_id = serializers.ReadOnlyField(source='id')
    related_order = serializers.IntegerField(source="order", required=False)

    id = serializers.ReadOnlyField(source='author.id')
    first_name = serializers.ReadOnlyField(source='author.first_name')
    last_name = serializers.ReadOnlyField(source='author.last_name')
    full_name = serializers.ReadOnlyField(source='author.full_name')


    class Meta:
        model = ArticleAuthors
        fields = ('related_id', 'related_order', 'id', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'full_name', )
        list_serializer_class = SelectRelatedListSerializer.factory(['author'])

class ArticleKeywordsSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    related_id = serializers.ReadOnlyField(source='id')
    related_order = serializers.IntegerField(source="order", required=False)

    id = serializers.ReadOnlyField(source='keyword.id')
    name = serializers.ReadOnlyField(source='keyword.name')
    slug = serializers.ReadOnlyField(source='keyword.slug')

    class Meta:
        model = ArticleKeywords
        fields = ('related_id', 'related_order', 'id', 'name', 'slug', )
        list_serializer_class = SelectRelatedListSerializer.factory(['keyword'])


class ArticleSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    user_created = UserSerializer(read_only=True)
    authors = ArticleAuthorsSerializer(source='articleauthors_set', many=True, read_only=False, )
    keywords = ArticleKeywordsSerializer(source='articlekeywords_set', many=True, read_only=False, )


    class Meta:
        model = Article
        fields = ('id', 'title', 'slug', 'intro', 'content', 'date_created',
        'date_published', 'date_modified', 'state', 'user_created',
        'authors', 'keywords', 'url')
```

When I send for example keywords like array of dicts in form like this:

```
.....
keywords:[
    {id:1},
    {id:2}
]
......
```

They got saved and everything is updated without a problem. But my idea is to have a shorthand soultion on frontend side and send just arrays of integers which would be represent ids. When I try to do that like this:

```
.....
keywords:[1,2]
......
```

I get following response in rest gui:

```
{
"keywords": [
    {
        "non_field_errors": [
            "Invalid data. Expected a dictionary, but got int."
        ]
    },
    {
        "non_field_errors": [
            "Invalid data. Expected a dictionary, but got int."
        ]
    },
 }
```

My idea was to override this to send further like dicts or something in view **perform_update** and **perform_create** metods but that is already too late from program perspective.

I though that best way is to catch those values before validation and turn list of integers to list of dicts and pass further in the process, but I can not find the way of doing this. Is this possible and how exactly? Or should I write custom validation?

Answer (score 0):

> My idea was to override this to send further like dicts or something in view perform_update and perform_create metods but that is already too late from program perspective.

You are right, it is too late to do it there. If you look into the code from DRF (in [mixins.py](https://github.com/tomchristie/django-rest-framework/blob/master/rest_framework/mixins.py)), you will see that `.is_valid()` is called before `.perform_create()` or `.perform_update()`.

So, the way I see it, you have two options:

1. In your view, you override the `.post()` and `.put()` methods, and you do the modifications to your integers list before calling `.is_valid()`. This would go something like this:

   ```
   def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
       // HERE transform your data as you wish
       return self.create(request, *args, **kwargs)
   ```
2. The second idea would be not to pass in a nested serializer for keywords, and just let DRF handle deserialization. This means you could remove the line `keywords = ArticleKeywordsSerializer(...)` and when you receive your json, DRF will automatically expect a list of integers (named articlekeywords_set). In this case, however, you will need different serializers for GET and POST (assuming you want to send nested objects).

Don't forget that for the first option, you will still have to override the `.create()` and `.update()` methods on your serializer, as DRF no longer supports  writable nested serialization (see [Writable nested serialization](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/topics/3.0-announcement/)).

Comment: thanks for suggestion. I must catch some time to try your suggestion, will let you know the result :)